# How to Retrieve Data from Firebase Realtime Database in Android ListView?

Tags: java, firebase

struktur on the firebase

-tools

- dhjjkghehjkhj (key from firebase)

  - name tools
    0: ampere meter
    1: multimeter
    2: wrench
    3: manometer
    4: computer
    5: Mistar
  - status : damage

output on the ListView

**DAMAGE**
ampere meter
multitester
wrench
manometer
computer
mistar

Comment: Instead of describing what your database looks like, please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Besides that, show us what you have tried so far.